# Change Color in v-textarea in vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js

I am trying to change color of text using style css in v-textarea but it only change outline

```
<v-textarea style="color:blue"></v-textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style>
  .my-textarea textarea { color: blue !important }
</style>
<v-textarea class="my-textarea"></v-textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of F.NiX will be correct if you want your style to be applied globally.

If you work in a component and must stay in a scoped style. You must provide deep selector because this is a dynamic generated content.

```
<v-textarea
   class="my-textarea">
</v-textarea>

<style scoped>
   .code-style /deep/ textarea{
      color:red !important;
   }
</style>
```